# how to avoid " Auto grid alignment" in bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to do something like,

______Empty space__________________|-----first column(aligned to right)-----|

|--logo--|____Empty space_____________|----second Column(aligned to right)----|

but its auto aligning into the empty space left by my first column like this,

|--logo--||-------second col------------||------------first column----------|

why is that and how to fix this?

Comment: I recommend that you read this document if you're going to attempt to use bootstrap: https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/#how-it-works

Comment: better to align content using pull left/right won't burst in multi screens

Comment: thank you, I dint read it until now .It cleared all of my doubts.@Hewlett

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use offsets. Look at the
example from the docs:
http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-offsetting

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-offset-6 col-md-6">first column right</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-2">Logo</div>
  <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-5">second column</div>
</div>
```

..

Answer (score 0):

Use the `.col-*-offset-*` class, this will push your div to the right based on the grid system of Bootstrap, example:

```
<div class="col-md-offset-3"></div>
```

This will push the div 3 columns to the right